# Width issue in a UITextField with custom rightView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` (placed inside a `UITableViewCell`) that has a `UIButton` as a custom `rightView`:

```
    UITextField *textField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 1.0, cell.bounds.size.width - 20.0, 31.0)] autorelease];
    textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 27.0, 31.0); // Probably not needed, doesn't change anything
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 27.0, 31.0);
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"27x31.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    textField.rightView = button;                                
    textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;
```

When the text field is shown, touches are not handled as expected:

- If I touch the button, it is triggered.
- If I touch an area close to the left edge of the button (but outside its bounds), the button is still triggered.
- If I want to edit the text in the text field rather than trigger the button, I have to touch further to the left.

Things get worse if I rotate the device to landscape mode. In this case, the area to the left of the button that still triggers the button is wider, and there's a gap to the left of this area that does nothing - the button is not triggered and the text is not edited. I have to move a considerable way to the left to edit the text in this situation.

This only happens if the current text in the field is short. If the text fills the text field, touches are handled as expected (touches anywhere to the left of the button edit the text in both portrait and landscape).

I tried to override `textRectForBounds`, `editingRectForBounds` and `rightViewRectForBounds`. I verified that they are called and return the correct values, but they don't change anything (as long as the return values are correct).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm having the same problem currently.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with a rightView that seemed to prevent a portion of the textfield from accepting input. My rightView was not a button so I simply set it's userInteractionEnabled to NO and the textfield started receiving touches again across its entire area.

Since you have a button as a rightView this might not help much. But another similarity between our examples was that both rightViews had a small width. Perhaps the rightView doesn't like having a width < x.

Comment: Bingo!  That did it.  I have spent forever trying to figure out what I was doing to block input (I was using a leftView and leftViewMode).  Setting userInteractionEnabled on my padding view seems to fix it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set any autoresize properties to the TableViewCell? Try adding:

```
[cell setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

and the textField and button set the `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` option like this:

```
[textField setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];

[button setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```

Comment: Setting the autoResizingMask for the UITableViewCell is not necessary, it inherits from the UITableView (and I did try it, no change). The UITextField already has an autoresizing mask (see the code), and the button shouldn't be resized since it's an image-based button.